# Oracle regexp_substr - Find and extract all occurances in a column

Tags: sql, oracle, regexp-substr

I'm working with an Oracle DB and I'm trying to find and extract ALL occurrences in a string matching a specific pattern...

It's supposed to be 3 letters, 3 numbers and then maybe a letter or not

I tried this:

```
SELECT REGEXP_SUBSTR(my_column, '[A-Za-z]{3}(\d)(\d)(\d)') AS values 
FROM my_table
```

but it only returns the first occurrence.

Using

```
REGEXP_SUBSTR(my_column, '[A-Za-z]{3}(\d)(\d)(\d)', 0, 0, 'i')
```

doesn't work either

Does anybody have any ideas?

**Edit:**

I'm trying to extract it from PLSQL files. So its pretty much like SQL queries like

```
select * 
from abc123 
where some_value = 'some_value'
```

Comment: Please post some sample data and desired result; for example, what do you expect from 'ABC123CDE456FGHI789' ?

Comment: regexp_substr cant accpet 0 as parameter.

Comment: @sanjay radadiya
Yes it can accept 0 as a parameter. just not for Position. You can use it for the occurance parameter ...

Comment: give sample data as @aleksej suggest so its clear what you want .

Comment: @Aleksej
 From your string i would expect
'ABC123', 'CDE456'

Comment: Why not even 'GHI789' ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this query to break  **ABC123CDE456FGHI789**  squence

```
with mine as (select 'ABC123CDE456FGH789' hello from dual) 
select regexp_substr(hello, '[A-Za-z]{3}(\d){3}', 1, level) STR from mine
connect by regexp_substr(hello, '[A-Za-z]{3}(\d){3}', 1, level) is not null
```

**Output**

```
ABC123
CDE456
GHI789
```

For get specific postion then you want to use

```
select regexp_substr('ABC123CDE456FGH789', '[A-Za-z]{3}(\d){3}', 1, i) STR from dual
```

change i value as per position like

```
select regexp_substr('ABC123CDE456FGH789', '[A-Za-z]{3}(\d){3}', 1, 1) STR from dual
```

**Output :**

```
ABC123
```

Comment: Thanks alot. this really helps me.

Comment: level query and regular expression is system facility so its always fast as compare to retrieve data from database.

Answer (score 1):

Try to get number in **1.2.3** (suppose it is a domain of a country)

```
SELECT str,level,REGEXP_SUBSTR(str, '[0-9]', 1, LEVEL) AS substr
FROM (
SELECT country_domain str from country where regexp_like(country_domain, '[0-9]')
)
CONNECT BY LEVEL <= REGEXP_count(str, '[0-9]');
```

**Output**

```
STR    LEVEL SUBSTR
1.2.3   1     1
1.2.3   2     2
1.2.3   3     3
```